# Joining fields from different files based on a number range

Tags: bash, perl, awk, range

I have three files with mostly similar information, but one unique filed. I want to combine these into one file. What the files have in common is the columns with the heading hs and the columns with the heading range1 and range2. The columns which are different are those labelled f1c, f2c and f3c. I want to combine the files based on what regions overlap within range1 and range2 (the hs columns must also match in this situation).

Its like the ranges are two bars, bar1(hs1) has 350 sections and bar2(hs2) has 700 sections. The values under f1c f2c and f3c all fit within a certain amount of these sections on either bar. For the values that fit within the same section, I want to list them beside each other.

Any sort of solution in bash, awk or perl would work, I'm just not sure how I can match these things up based on the ranges.

Here is an example of the files

First file format

```
hs  f1c range1 range2
hs1 p32 0      200
hs1 p31 200    300
hs1 p30 300    350
hs2 p32 0      300
hs2 p31 300    500
hs2 p30 500    700
```

Second file Format

```
f2c       hs     range1 range2
DDX11L1   hs1    20     50
FAM41C    hs1    50     70
WASH7P    hs1    70     120
FAM138A   hs1    180    250
OR4F5     hs2    0      50
KLHL17    hs2    50     100
PLEKHN1   hs2    100    150
LOC729737 hs2    300    500 
HES4      hs2    500    600
ISG15     hs2    600    700
```

Third file format

```
hs  range1 range2 f3c
hs1 0      200    -1
hs1 200    350    -2
hs2 0      500    -1
hs2 500    700    -2
```

Here is an example of the desired output (There is an n under f2c if there is no value within file2 that is within the range)

```
hs    f1c   f2c      range1 range2 f3c
hs1   p32   n         0      20     -1   // From the 1st line of file3, and the 1st line of file1
hs1   p32   DDX11L1   20     50     -1   // From the 1st line of file1, 1st line of file2 and 1st line of file3
hs1   p32   FAM41C    50     70     -1   // From the 1st line of file1, 2nd line of file2 and 1st line of file3
hs1   p32   WASH7P    70     120    -1   // 1st line file1, 3rd line file2, first line file3
hs1   p32   n         120    180    -1   // 1st line file1, 1st line file3
hs1   p32   FAM13BA   180    200    -1   // 1st line file1, 4th line file2, 1st line file3
hs1   p31   FAM13BA   200    250.   -2   // 2nd line file1, 4th line file2, 2nd line file3
hs1   p31   n         250.   300    -2   // 2nd line file1, 2nd line file3
hs1   p30   n         300    350    -2   // 3rd line file1, 2nd line file3
hs2   p32   OR4FS     0      50     -1
hs2   p32   KLHL17    50     100    -1
hs2   p32   PLEKHN1   100    150    -1
hs2   p32   n         150    300    -1
hs2   p31   LOC729737 300    500    -1
hs2   p30   HES4      500    600    -2
hs2   p30   ISG15     600    700    -2
```

Thank-you

Comment: You have lots of sample input and output, but no code! Where's the code you've written, and what's wrong with it? See: [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Please show a header for the desired output file.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code (if you don't have any code yet, then Stack Overflow is probably the wrong place to ask your question).

Comment: How big are the real files?

Comment: @agc: It would be `hs  f1c  f2c  range1  range2  f3c`. The OP also omitted to say that the `f2c` column should be set to `n` if there is no value in the second file for the range.

Comment: I'm assuming that the last line of the second data file should be `ISG15       hs2    600  700` (600 instead of 500) since none of the other ranges overlap.

Comment: How can the second line of output be `Dox11L1` when the input is `DDX11L1`?

Comment: @Borodin You're correct about you're last three comments. The real files are thousands of lines

Comment: @Jacob: What size are the files, in KB or MB?

Comment: @DaveCross I did not have any code yet. I wasn't sure how I could match these things up and any sort of advice or guidance I could get would have been good

Comment: @Borodin first file: 40K, second file: 1.3M, third file 4K. They're not all thousands of lines, sorry

Comment: @Jacob: That should be okay. If the files had been enormous then there was a chance that my solution would run out of memory. It will probably take several seconds to run but it should produce the result that you want. Have you tried it with live data yet?

Comment: @Borodin Not yet, I will have to in a few hours, thank-you

Comment: @Jacob: If you don't have any code, then Stack Overflow is not the right site to be asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written this to help you, but you need to understand that your question is unacceptable on a site that offers diagnostic help for free. You can't simply put up your requirement and wait for a high-quality free solution to pop up. I wrote an answer only because it is a bank holiday in my country and the problem interested me

I have put a lot more effort into creating this than you obviously have in writing your question, and you haven't even been bothered to answer the several questions that people have asked you in the comments

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

use Readonly::Tiny 'Readonly';

Readonly my @FILES       => qw/ file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt /;
Readonly my $FORMAT      => "%-6s%-6s%-10s%-5d%-5d%d\n";
Readonly my @OUTPUT      => qw/ hs f1c f2c range1 range2 f3c /;
Readonly my @KEY_COLUMNS => qw/ hs range1 range2 /;

my %data;   # All the data for each value of `hs` 
my %bounds; # All the values of `range1` or `range2` for each value of `hs` 
my %heads;  # All the headers found in any of the files

# From each file, read the header line and use the
# headers as keys for the data hashes representing each line
#
for my $file ( @FILES ) {

    open my $fh, '<', $file; # Errors handled by `autodie`

    my @head = split ' ', <$fh>;
    @heads{@head} = ();

    while ( <$fh> ) {

        next unless /\S/;

        my %row;
        @row{@head} = split;

        my ($hs, $r1, $r2) = @row{ @KEY_COLUMNS };
        push @{ $data{$hs} }, \%row;

        ++$bounds{$hs}{$_} for $r1, $r2;
    }
}


# Change the `%bounds` hash values from
# hashes to sorted arrays of the boundary values
#
for ( values %bounds ) {

    my @vals = sort {
        my ($aa, $bb) = map { tr/0-9//cdr } $a, $b;
        $aa <=> $bb;
    } keys %$_;

    $_ = \@vals;
}

# Work through the `%bounds` hash
# printing a line of output for each range
#
for my $hs ( sort keys %bounds ) {

    my $bounds = $bounds{$hs};
    my $data   = $data{$hs};

    for my $i ( 1 .. $#$bounds ) {

        my ($r1, $r2) = map { $bounds->[$_] } $i-1, $i;

        my @matches = grep {
            $r1 >= $_->{range1} and $r2 <= $_->{range2}
        } @$data;

        my %row;

        for my $match ( @matches ) {
            @row{ keys %$match } = values %$match;
        }

        @row{ @KEY_COLUMNS } = ($hs, $r1, $r2); # Overwrite in the new key values

        printf $FORMAT, map { $_ // 'n' } @row{ @OUTPUT };
    }
}
```

#### output

```
hs1   p32   n         0    20   -1
hs1   p32   DDX11L1   20   50   -1
hs1   p32   FAM41C    50   70   -1
hs1   p32   WASH7P    70   120  -1
hs1   p32   n         120  180  -1
hs1   p32   FAM138A   180  200  -1
hs1   p31   FAM138A   200  250  -2
hs1   p31   n         250  300  -2
hs1   p30   n         300  350  -2
hs2   p32   OR4F5     0    50   -1
hs2   p32   KLHL17    50   100  -1
hs2   p32   PLEKHN1   100  150  -1
hs2   p32   n         150  300  -1
hs2   p31   LOC729737 300  500  -1
hs2   p30   HES4      500  600  -2
hs2   p30   ISG15     600  700  -2
```

Comment: Thanks, it works good, but for every region which does not show up in file3 I get this error `Argument "n" isn't numeric in printf at ./script.pl line 81.
hsX   p11   n         530       535     0`. This doesn't seem to be a problem for me right now however because things still print but do you know whats going on?

Comment: @Jacob: What do you want in that column for a missing value? `n`, or zero `0`? How long does it take to run?